# Change PouchDB storage directory

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB with nodejs. When creating a database, a directory is created with the name of the database. How can I change where this directory is created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can currently specify the directory of the db file when you open the database

```
new PouchDB('~/myapp/db/');
```

We are considering changing the API @ https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/issues/998 so I would also watch that for changes

Comment: Note that this will only work if all directories (except the last one) exist, as `fs.mkdir()` doesn't recursively create subdirectories if needed but instead throws an `ENOENT` error.

Comment: Despite Dale's comment, this still works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using PouchDB with LevelDB. From [the source code of PouchDB](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/blob/v0.0.10/src/adapters/pouch.leveldb.js#L68-L74), this looks like it is impossible at the moment, as PouchDB uses the database name for the directory name:

```
fs.stat(opts.name, function(err, stats) {
  if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
    // db directory doesn't exist
    fs.mkdir(opts.name, initstores);
  }
  else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    initstores();
  }
  else {
    // error
  }
}
```

and [here is the relevant source code](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/blob/v0.0.10/src/pouch.js#L65-L87) that matches a database identifier with a database name and database type.